# Is there a faster way to match common elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a n-length 2d array of strings I need to return an n x n array that does a simple matching operation across itself. The matching operation is checking if the sub arrays are exactly the same (return 2), share a common element (return 1), or neither (return 0).  This is implemented as:

```
def match(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    if a_set == b_set:
        return 2
    elif a_set & b_set:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

example:

```
arr = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['d', 'e']])
array([['a', 'b'],
   ['a', 'b'],
   ['a', 'c'],
   ['d', 'e']], dtype='<U1')
```

should return:

```
[[2, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2]]
```

My current solution below works fine but doesn't scale very well. Looking for something that could run quickly on 50k elements in a couple of seconds.

```
np.reshape(np.array([match(i, j) for i, j in it.product(arr, repeat=2)]),(len(arr),len(arr)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
(arr == arr[:, None]).sum(axis=2)
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]])
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect. I am starting from a 2d list and using product to make the pairs to compare. the issue with this solution is that the sub list sizes are not always the same and I can't create jagged arrays in numpy. I tried to resolve it by padding each sub array. Issue with that is if you pad everything with the same string it thinks they have an item in common. if you pad with different  strings then you don't catch instances where two arrays might be the same. maybe can try to pad arrays that are the same with the same element. that may be slow with a large array but I can try

Comment: A 'jagged array' is virtually the same thing as a list.  So you are stuck with this kind of padding, or a python based loop or comprehension.  Even with padding, array matching is an expensive operation - either with broadcasting lilke this, or sorting as used by `unique` or `isin`.